# Applying a Popover Message Box OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to this. I found an example of popover message box in the link below. I tried to implement it and it doesn't seem to work am i missing something?

Or is their an easier way to implement a popover message box (onclick) that looks like the on in the image.

Link: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-individual-compiled

Image: [image]

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on left
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on top
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on bottom
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on right
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popover functionality is optional in Bootstrap. You need to enable it by adding the following code:

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
</script>
```